# How to make the radio button look like this design when selected/checked?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the radio button so that when one is selected, it looks like this (the left/first one):

[image: selected radio button]

This is the code I have so far:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300);

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .red {
  border: 2px solid #711313;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .orange {
  border: 2px solid #873a08;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .yellow {
  border: 2px solid #816102;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .olive {
  border: 2px solid #505a0b;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .green {
  border: 2px solid #0e4e1d;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .teal {
  border: 2px solid #003633;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .blue {
  border: 2px solid #103f62;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .violet {
  border: 2px solid #321a64;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .purple {
  border: 2px solid #501962;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .pink {
  border: 2px solid #851554;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
label span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
label span.red {
  background: #db2828;
}
label span.orange {
  background: #f2711c;
}
label span.yellow {
  background: #fbbd08;
}
label span.olive {
  background: #b5cc18;
}
label span.green {
  background: #21ba45;
}
label span.teal {
  background: #00b5ad;
}
label span.blue {
  background: #2185d0;
}
label span.violet {
  background: #6435c9;
}
label span.purple {
  background: #a333c8;
}
label span.pink {
  background: #e03997;
}
```

```html
<h1>Radio Color Picker</h1>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" />
<label for="red"><span class="red"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="green" />
<label for="green"><span class="green"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="yellow" />
<label for="yellow"><span class="yellow"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="olive" />
<label for="olive"><span class="olive"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="orange" />
<label for="orange"><span class="orange"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="teal" />
<label for="teal"><span class="teal"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" />
<label for="blue"><span class="blue"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="violet" />
<label for="violet"><span class="violet"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="purple" />
<label for="purple"><span class="purple"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="pink" />
<label for="pink"><span class="pink"></span></label>
```

As you can see, in this codepen, when you select a radio button, this rule is added:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

So the buttons will become bigger when they are selected. But I want them to keep their size and the background color covers a smaller circle than the rest. The part for adding border color is already there. How do I make this happen?

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question, please do not just link to external platforms.

Comment: @CBroe I'm gonna edit my question and add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outline` property might be useful here (add outline instead of border and change width and height when checked)
By changing `outline-offset` and `width`, `height` you can adjust the amount of indentation

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300);

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  /* changed */
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  outline-offset: 4px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .red {
  outline: 2px solid #711313;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .orange {
  outline: 2px solid #873a08;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .yellow {
  outline: 2px solid #816102;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .olive {
  outline: 2px solid #505a0b;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .green {
  outline: 2px solid #0e4e1d;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .teal {
  outline: 2px solid #003633;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .blue {
  outline: 2px solid #103f62;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .violet {
  outline: 2px solid #321a64;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .purple {
  outline: 2px solid #501962;/* changed */
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .pink {
  outline: 2px solid #851554;/* changed */
}


label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover span {
  /*transform: scale(1.25);*/
}
label span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
label span.red {
  background: #db2828;
}
label span.orange {
  background: #f2711c;
}
label span.yellow {
  background: #fbbd08;
}
label span.olive {
  background: #b5cc18;
}
label span.green {
  background: #21ba45;
}
label span.teal {
  background: #00b5ad;
}
label span.blue {
  background: #2185d0;
}
label span.violet {
  background: #6435c9;
}
label span.purple {
  background: #a333c8;
}
label span.pink {
  background: #e03997;
}
```

```html
<h1>Radio Color Picker</h1>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" />
<label for="red"><span class="red"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="green" />
<label for="green"><span class="green"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="yellow" />
<label for="yellow"><span class="yellow"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="olive" />
<label for="olive"><span class="olive"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="orange" />
<label for="orange"><span class="orange"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="teal" />
<label for="teal"><span class="teal"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" />
<label for="blue"><span class="blue"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="violet" />
<label for="violet"><span class="violet"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="purple" />
<label for="purple"><span class="purple"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="pink" />
<label for="pink"><span class="pink"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try these styles (I havent given the exact colors please use the below css and match the color)

```
input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span::after {
  background-color: #f00;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Remove your entire css and give this and try hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There's one approach, below – with explanatory comments in the code – which simplifies your CSS a little and, then, there's a modification to that approach which – *perhaps* – further simplifies your code, using the CSS `color-mix()` function. There are also linked demonstrations, following the examples, over on JS Fiddle to experiment with:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300);

/* s simple reset to remove browser default padding and margin from
   elements, and to ensure that all elements are sized according to
   the border-box algorithm, including border-width and padding
   inside the declared element sizes (width, height, inline-size and
   block-size: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* setting the <body> to occupy 100% of the block-axis of the viewport,
   the block-axis is the axis on which block elements are laid out, in
   in most languages that read left-to-right, or right-to-left, this
   will be the vertical axis, so block-size would - in most situations -
   be equivalent to 'height', but will automatically adjust to languages
   that read top-to-bottom: */
body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
}

section {
  /* setting custom properties to ensure that all - in this case -
     transitions use the same duration and timing function: */
  --animationDuration: 0.2s;
  --animationTimingFunction: ease-in-out;
  /* using flex layout on the wrapper element of the content in
     your demo: */
  display: flex;
  /* because the <h1> should be on a separate line of its own,
     we're using flex-flow shorthand to set
      flex-direction: row; (the default, but I prefer to specify),
      flex-direction: wrap; (the default is nowrap, to prevent wrapping)
  */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* a gap between adjacent items of 1rem: */
  gap: 1rem;
  /* justifying child-elements to the start of the flex-axis, which
     is to the left in left-to-right languages: */
  justify-content: start;
}

h1 {
  /* to have the <h1> take a row to itself, we set its base-size to
     100%, this forces subsequent content to a new row: */
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

/* hiding the <input> elements: */
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

/* setting custom properties for each element, in order to reduce
   huge amounts of potential repetition: */
.red {
  --border: #711313;
  --bg: #db2828;
}

.orange {
  --bg: #f2711c;
  --border: #873a08;
}

.yellow {
  --bg: #fbbd08;
  --border: #816102;
}

.olive {
  --bg: #b5cc18;
  --border: #505a0b;
}

.green {
  --bg: #21ba45;
  --border: #0e4e1d;
}

.teal {
  --bg: #00b5ad;
  --border: #003633;
}

.blue {
  --bg: #2185d0;
  --border: #103f62;
}

.violet {
  --bg: #6435c9;
  --border: #321a64;
}

.purple {
  --bg: #a333c8;
  --border: #501962;
}

.pink {
  --bg: #e03997;
  --border: #851554;
}

label {
  /* using the aspect-ratio property to set the aspect-ratio to 1,
     this ensures that the element's inline-size is equal to its
     block-size, specifying only one of those dimensions (though
     you could instead specify both of course), this allows you
     to change only one number to affect all elements on both
     axes: */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  inline-size: 36px;
}

label span {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  /* using the custom property for the background-color: */
  background-color: var(--bg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  inline-size: 100%;
  /* using an outline for the inner white border of the
     :checked element; currently this is non-visible: */
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 0;
  /* defining a transition for both the outline and transform,
     using the custom properties defined earlier: */
  transition: outline var(--animationDuration) var(--animationTimingFunction), transform var(--animationDuration) var(--animationTimingFunction);
}

input:checked+label span {
  /* using the custom properties to set the border-color: */
  border: 2px solid var(--border);
  /* updating the outline: */
  outline: 2px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Radio Color Picker</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" />
  <label for="red"><span class="red"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="green" />
  <label for="green"><span class="green"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="yellow" />
  <label for="yellow"><span class="yellow"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="olive" />
  <label for="olive"><span class="olive"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="orange" />
  <label for="orange"><span class="orange"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="teal" />
  <label for="teal"><span class="teal"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" />
  <label for="blue"><span class="blue"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="violet" />
  <label for="violet"><span class="violet"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="purple" />
  <label for="purple"><span class="purple"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="pink" />
  <label for="pink"><span class="pink"></span></label>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v6tc9qwm/).

Of course, if you wanted to adjust the `border-color`, or `outline`, to be adjusted shades of the `background-color`, rather than predefined hard-coded colours, it's possible to combine the above approach to use the `color-mix()` function, as follows:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300);

/* s simple reset to remove browser default padding and margin from
   elements, and to ensure that all elements are sized according to
   the border-box algorithm, including border-width and padding
   inside the declared element sizes (width, height, inline-size and
   block-size: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* setting the <body> to occupy 100% of the block-axis of the viewport,
   the block-axis is the axis on which block elements are laid out, in
   in most languages that read left-to-right, or right-to-left, this
   will be the vertical axis, so block-size would - in most situations -
   be equivalent to 'height', but will automatically adjust to languages
   that read top-to-bottom: */
body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
}

section {
  /* setting custom properties to ensure that all - in this case -
     transitions use the same duration and timing function: */
  --animationDuration: 0.2s;
  --animationTimingFunction: ease-in-out;
  /* using flex layout on the wrapper element of the content in
     your demo: */
  display: flex;
  /* because the <h1> should be on a separate line of its own,
     we're using flex-flow shorthand to set
      flex-direction: row; (the default, but I prefer to specify),
      flex-direction: wrap; (the default is nowrap, to prevent wrapping)
  */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* a gap between adjacent items of 1rem: */
  gap: 1rem;
  /* justifying child-elements to the start of the flex-axis, which
     is to the left in left-to-right languages: */
  justify-content: start;
}

h1 {
  /* to have the <h1> take a row to itself, we set its base-size to
     100%, this forces subsequent content to a new row: */
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

/* hiding the <input> elements: */
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

/* setting custom properties for each element, in order to reduce
   huge amounts of potential repetition: */
.red {
  --border: #711313;
}

.orange {
  --bg: #f2711c;
}

.yellow {
  --bg: #fbbd08;
}

.olive {
  --bg: #b5cc18;
}

.green {
  --bg: #21ba45;
}

.teal {
  --bg: #00b5ad;
}

.blue {
  --bg: #2185d0;
}

.violet {
  --bg: #6435c9;
}

.purple {
  --bg: #a333c8;
}

.pink {
  --bg: #e03997;
}

label {
  /* using the aspect-ratio property to set the aspect-ratio to 1,
     this ensures that the element's inline-size is equal to its
     block-size, specifying only one of those dimensions (though
     you could instead specify both of course), this allows you
     to change only one number to affect all elements on both
     axes: */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  inline-size: 36px;
}

label span {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  /* using the custom property for the background-color: */
  background-color: var(--bg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  inline-size: 100%;
  /* using an outline for the inner white border of the
     :checked element; currently this is non-visible: */
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 0;
  /* defining a transition for both the outline and transform,
     using the custom properties defined earlier: */
  transition: outline var(--animationDuration) var(--animationTimingFunction), transform var(--animationDuration) var(--animationTimingFunction);
}

input:checked + label span {
  /* here we use the color-mix() function, we define the color-space ('in oklch'), we
     specify the base-color we wish to modify (var(--bg)) and the percentage of that
     base-color that should be in the resulting colour (80%), and finally the
     color we wish to mix with (#fff).
     The border-color will be close to the existing var(--bg) color, and only 20% white,
     whereas the lighter inset border, created by the outline-color, will be much closer
     to a solid white. The advantage of this approach is that we don't have to
     pre-calculate, and specify, the different colours: */
  border: 2px solid color-mix(in oklch, var(--bg) 80%, #fff);
  outline: 2px solid color-mix(in oklch, var(--bg) 15%, #fff);
  /* the outline-offset moves the outline 4px "inside" of the element it's outlining:  */
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Radio Color Picker</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" />
  <label for="red"><span class="red"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="green" />
  <label for="green"><span class="green"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="yellow" />
  <label for="yellow"><span class="yellow"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="olive" />
  <label for="olive"><span class="olive"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="orange" />
  <label for="orange"><span class="orange"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="teal" />
  <label for="teal"><span class="teal"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" />
  <label for="blue"><span class="blue"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="violet" />
  <label for="violet"><span class="violet"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="purple" />
  <label for="purple"><span class="purple"></span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="color" id="pink" />
  <label for="pink"><span class="pink"></span></label>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v6tc9qwm/1/).

References:

- [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).
- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`color-mix()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) ([compatibility](https://caniuse.com/?search=color-mix)).
- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values).
- [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).
- [`outline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by removing the transform scaling and adding an inset Box-shadow. The Box shadow needs to have 3 0's and then a fitting size, i used em here but you can use whatever you need. I commented the CSS accordingly.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300);

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  
  /*transform: scale(1); <- remove the scaling you dont need that*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.3em White; /*add an isnet box shadow with a fitting size*/
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .red {
  border: 2px solid #711313;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .orange {
  border: 2px solid #873a08;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .yellow {
  border: 2px solid #816102;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .olive {
  border: 2px solid #505a0b;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .green {
  border: 2px solid #0e4e1d;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .teal {
  border: 2px solid #003633;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .blue {
  border: 2px solid #103f62;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .violet {
  border: 2px solid #321a64;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .purple {
  border: 2px solid #501962;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label .pink {
  border: 2px solid #851554;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:hover span{ /*add this if you want to keep the hover effect*/
  transform: scale(1);
}
label span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
label span.red {
  background: #db2828;
}
label span.orange {
  background: #f2711c;
}
label span.yellow {
  background: #fbbd08;
}
label span.olive {
  background: #b5cc18;
}
label span.green {
  background: #21ba45;
}
label span.teal {
  background: #00b5ad;
}
label span.blue {
  background: #2185d0;
}
label span.violet {
  background: #6435c9;
}
label span.purple {
  background: #a333c8;
}
label span.pink {
  background: #e03997;
}
```

```html
<h1>Radio Color Picker</h1>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" />
<label for="red"><span class="red"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="green" />
<label for="green"><span class="green"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="yellow" />
<label for="yellow"><span class="yellow"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="olive" />
<label for="olive"><span class="olive"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="orange" />
<label for="orange"><span class="orange"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="teal" />
<label for="teal"><span class="teal"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" />
<label for="blue"><span class="blue"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="violet" />
<label for="violet"><span class="violet"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="purple" />
<label for="purple"><span class="purple"></span></label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="pink" />
<label for="pink"><span class="pink"></span></label>
```